# How to use vagrant to develop on django locally and then deploy to EC2/Azure?

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, vagrant

I chose Vagrant so that other developers in my team can quickly start contributing to the project. Is there anyway we can also make it easy for the developed code to be deployed on EC2 or Azure servers? If there are any articles on the optimal setup, please point me to them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The first video of [*Getting started with Django*](http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/) shows how to use Vagrant for locally Django developing and how to use it for deploying it to Heroku, you may want to use the first part of the tutorial (the one related with the local development). For the second it depends how you are going to deploy it, but as long as your code will be in a Git repository, you could clone it to EC2/azure from git.